# How to implement table list like google inbox ios app?

Tags: ios, email, animation, inbox

the google inbox app has a feature when select a cell the table will expand and insert a sublist table view. the sublist can also has sublist.
How to implement this feature with tableview, collection view or custom view?

Answer (score 0):

there are already some nice implementations like:

http://jackkwok.github.io/JKExpandTableView/

https://github.com/OliverLetterer/SLExpandableTableView

Comment: thanks for your answer, but google inbox is not just expand and insert some new cells, it expand and insert a new list or new scroll page.

Comment: in these implementations you can add whatever you like as expandable view too. you just have to customize that view.